# Share button on a https site

Tags: c#, iis, plugins

Hi can i integrate share buttons like facebook, twitter on my https site? Recently in my site i have integrated these buttons, but it looks like it prevents loading of these social media buttons since it is a https site. Is there any way to integrate these buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot load HTTP resources on an HTTPS page.
You need to load all external resources over HTTPS.